# Is it possible for a modern commercial airliner to stop being tracked without substantial mechanical failure?

Tags: avionics, radar, mh370-incident, gnss

I was speaking to someone about the [MH370 incident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370), and they suggested that a hijacker could turn off the device that sends the plane's current position, resulting in the appearance of a catastrophic midair failure.

I assume that such functionality could not be turned off, but I could be wrong. Is there any way that this could be done? Could an aircraft's internal tracking systems be "turned off" midair, and also not be located by external tracking like radar?

Comment: It's not your question, but even if what you propose is possible then it seems unlikely for such a large aircraft, if it were commandeered and rendered untraceable, to land at an airfield capable of accommodating it without drawing attention. Also, anyone commandeering such a high profile aircraft would likely *want* to draw public attention, an indispensable element of today's attacks. Nobody's (yet) claimed resp. for attacking the aircraft in question which, when coupled with reports it attempted to RTB, lends credence to either a catastrophic mech. failure or mech. failure & pilot error.

Comment: @cfx Yep. Another issue is that the moment the plane lands, or even gets close to landing, mobile phones would likely get some signal and people would be sending messages.

Comment: The transponder can be turned off at any time by anyone with access to the cockpit. You can also change the code on a transponder to any value. For example, you could change your code to match that of another aircraft so there was no way to tell the difference between them. You can also put the transponder on standby, so that it is on, but not transmitting.

Comment: why a Pilot can't be involved in doing all this turning off or routing to somewhere else?
if not a pilot crew person can get entry into cockpit allowing others (hijackers etc) to take control or force pilots to do exactly they want. cheers
Aman

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2278/193

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The device you are talking about is called a [transponder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transponder_%28aeronautics%29).  This is a device that listens for a signal (an interrogation) and responds with information about the airplane including an ATC assigned code, altitude information and additional aircraft info for certain equipment.

There are 2 ways ATC watches airplanes:

- [Primary Radar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_surveillance_radar#Primary_radar)
- [Secondary Surveillance Radar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_surveillance_radar#Secondary_radar)

The transponder is interrogated by the Secondary radar and the response is listened for.  Even with no transponder, the aircraft can still be tracked by primary radar.  This is just a normal radar that is good at seeing airplane sized objects and not so great at seeing weather and can occasionally spot a large flock of birds.  The primary radar is what provides the "blip" on radar and tracks the airplane.  The datablock ATC has on the airplane comes from the secondary, so what ATC will see is a blip with no information.  Turning off the transponder is as simple as setting it to OFF or pulling a circuit breaker and yes, it can be selected OFF in flight, it is just a switch.

The problem with radar is that it only works so far from a radar transmitter and the further away you are the higher you must be to be seen by the radar.  Over the ocean away from land, you are going to be on the fringe of radar or out of radar contact completely and thus unable to be tracked directly by ATC (at this point, non-radar procedures such as position reporting and ETAs can be used to track positions).

The flight in question was apparently visible by a military radar before it disappeared from the scopes (it allegedly observed what appeared to be a turn back toward its origin).

Comment: That's amazing, I figured a vehicle of that size would surely have something like GPS hardwired into its operations. From my layman perspective regarding aviation, looks like this'll be a bit of a kick in the pants in regards to airplane tracking. Are there easy avenues to improve it? Or is something like GPS not so accessible to planes?

Comment: Even better, many commercial radars aren't even radars as such, they're just displays that show the location information sent out by transponders. Or if they do have an actual radar, it's usually turned off to prevent cluttering the displays with spurious information like flocks of migratory birds.

Comment: @andrewb GPS is available but currently not commonly used by traffic control, blame legacy aircraft for that: you'd have to refit thousands of aircraft with a GPS, and that can then also be turned off

Comment: @ratchetfreak GPS+Sattelite phone connection in a closed box somewhere out of reach during flight couldn't be at least turned of during flight. Hearing about the incident I, like andrewb, was similarly amazed, but remembered a talk about how airplane soft and hardware are 20 years out of date (stability over security and development) and I guess it makes sense from that point of view.

Comment: @andrewb There are other ways that an airplane transmits it's location, both to ATC and to their company headquarters for flight tracking purposes. Many (especially newer) aircraft **do** have GPS that automatically transmits the position, however the communication system can be turned off if you know how....

Comment: @DavidMulder Virtually everything on an airplane can hire turned off, it's just a matter of how. There are circuit breakers designed to protect the system that can be pulled, or even just turn off the batteries and generators for the entire airplane....

Comment: @Lnafziger: Still, looking at it as a developer (and security developer) it seems... quite an obvious thing to add a self contained GPS+Sattelite phone+Battery. By default it will be connected to the power source, in case the power source fails it would switch to the battery. Additionally it would be connected to a couple of external sensors (which could probably be turned of with the right know how), still it sounds similar to programming where an error handling routine will not be dependent on any routines in the main program.

Comment: @DavidMulder The main problem in an airplane is that it needs to be designed for when things go wrong. What happens if there is an electrical short which causes a fire?  What about a malfunction that causes electrical interference with other systems?  They both happen.  There needs to be a way to turn it off in cases like these in order to protect the aircraft in a "worst case scenario" for the electronic component.

Comment: @Lnafziger: Can't remember last time my phone (or any phone) burst out into flames. And it's practically the same hardware (different chip for the transmission, but even that one isn't drawing enough power to cause such a short if designed correctly). And it's not like interference will magically manifest itself *during* a flight. Of course you would have to test it, and for sure there are procedures how to do those tests, but it's not without a reason that on the software side airplanes are a terrible mess. And solving them with the mindset you describe is never gonna happen.

Comment: @DavidMulder I'm with Lnafziger on this one; any thing powered needs a fuse (all accessible behind the captain), adding a battery just adds the risk of it leaking/exploding due to overcurrent cause be faulty wire somewhere else and damaging other things

Comment: @Both of you: You gotta be kidding me, I am quite the privacy advocate, but whoever came up with the idea that the user (pilot) should be in control over those kind of things with aircrafts... It's RIDICULOUS that in the modern age we don't know +- 15m where a crash happened. Or that *any* consideration can be given to an airplane getting hijacked/stolen. I mean, as far as I care you may put that phone (which it boils down to being) into a second black box with just the antenna and main power coming from the outside, but this reminds me of http://xkcd.com/463/

Comment: @DavidMulder Yes, interference can just "magically manifest itself during a flight" when a component on a circuit board fails. Electrical wiring or pretty much any component on a circuit board can fail and create a hazard. That's why almost everything is protected with independent systems so that you don't lose the entire electrical system just because the sat phone shorted out. I'm not talking about the software side of things, just basic electrical hardware protection design. I'm a pilot who happens to be an electrical engineer. Let me assure you that it isn't as simple as you think.

Comment: @DavidMulder - Perhaps you recall the 787 recall that happened a few months back?  Faulty lithium ion batteries that started a fire, same batteries as what you see on a cell phone...  Look, nobody is saying you are wrong, we all know it ought to be done.  It's just about 100 times harder to do on an airplane than it is to do in consumer electronics.  There is a failure rate with consume electronics, companies have whole entire tech supports to fix their customers problems, and that's fine.  But an airplane...a failure just makes the plane crash, so designers have to be very very very careful.

Comment: @DavidMulder: While _my_ phone never burst into flames, I certainly _do_ remember handful of cases where electronic items did, including one relatively recent where [camera just burst into flames in someone's hand luggage](http://avherald.com/h?article=43d462c7).

Comment: @DavidMulder This conversation has gone far enough as a comment thread and is not what comments are designed for. If you have an interest in more information about this topic, please ask your own question where we can offer full answers (with formatting, pictures, and hyperlinks) to better address your question/concerns and get different feedback from different people.  You are also welcome to drop by [chat] if you just want to talk about it with other people in the industry. I understand your point of view, but there **are** technical reasons why things are the way that they are on airplanes.

Comment: and if the pilot knows the area and terrain, he can always reduce altitude and use terrain masking (of course in populated areas that'd lead to visual detection and people calling the police).

Comment: The JACC confirmed in an interview between Sir Angus Houston and the Malaysian Chronicle on 24 June 2014 that MH370 was not seen on radar climbing to 45,000ft nor turning west and diving to low altitude. There was no such radar data.

Answer (score 18):

With the proper knowledge of the aircraft systems almost anything can be turned off.  That's what we do at the end of almost every flight day.  Most of the communications systems can actually be turned off fairly easily, but the average person would not know how to do it.

In airplanes like the 777, there are multiple ways that they communicate but all of them can be turned off (transponders, ACARS reports, CPDLC, ADS-B, radios, satellite phones, etc.).  Some are automatic and some are manual,  and not all aircraft have all of them.  Most of them have a switch or can be controlled through the Flight Management System, but the ones that don't will have a circuit breaker designed to protect the system which may be pulled in order to deactivate the system.

Answer (score 8):

As a B-737 pilot, I can tell you that ALL electrical components are wired into the electrical system to a specific electrical BUS. It would not be hard to determine which BUS(S) run power to the associated component and therefore knowing which circuit breaker(s) to pull. The ACARS that transmits our FOQA information can be disconnected on the BBJ I fly. I assume it can be done in the B-777.

Comment: Not only that, I assume that you can just turn off the satellite and VHF data communication directly from your FMS.  (At least I can on my airplane!)

Comment: Yes. I provided the information in my answer:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/7787/22550

Answer (score 7):

With today's locked cockpit policy it is extremely unlikely that hijackers would be able to turn off the transponder without pilots being able to set it to 7500, the code for unlawful interference, for at least a short while. Because while the transponder can be turned off, the hijackers would have to get into the cockpit first.

The cockpit door *can't* be opened from cabin side. Even if the stronger code is entered that will open the door (for cases when one pilot is incapacitated while the other is in the lavatory) the pilots still have some time to cancel the unlock request. Therefore the hijackers would have to threaten with something to get the pilots unlock, but that would give the pilots time to provide some indication of the hijack to the ATC.

Comment: Setting the transponder to 7500 when out of radar range won't help.

Comment: Also clever social manipulation combined with poor pilot practices could get you in there. There's also the possibility that a pilot could be in on it.

Comment: Had another quick look at the news and it turns out the pilot has a history of letting people into the cockpit! http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/mar/11/malaysian-flight-mh370-copilot-teenagers-fariq-abdul-hamid

Comment: @andrewb: Interesting...

Comment: « With today's locked cockpit policy »? I succeeded to enter a 747 cockpit last year during the flight (end of cruise and begin of descent). Just needed to smile to the purser and say "I'm PPL". But it will depend of course on the airline, and the current crew.

Comment: re: *"Setting the transponder to 7500 when out of radar range won't help."* – MH370 was **not** out of radar range when it was diverted.

Answer (score 1):

Another Boeing 777 on 12th July 2014 suffered smoke in the cockpit and cascading loss of electrical systems, navigation displays and Comms in the cockpit. That was Continental Flight 201 which made an emergency landing on Midway island.

There are disputed claims that flight 201's transponder also failed during the emergency.

In the case of MH370 it is acknowledged that the ACARS suffered a power interruption prior to log-on requests. It seems possible that the transponder was affected by whatever power interruption the ACARS suffered therefore it is not an automatic assumption that the transponder and ACARS were turned off deliberately.

Comment: With Continental Flight 201, did they lose all transponder capabilities?

Comment: *"radar data indicate the transponder worked until touchdown."* - [Aviation Herald](http://avherald.com/h?article=47729f02)

Answer (score 1):

The plane's position is reported by ACARS and by the transponder.

[MH370](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370) lost ...

- ... its [Mode S transponder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transponder) (shortly before 17:20:33 UTC)
- ... [ACARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Communications_Addressing_and_Reporting_System) (somewhere between 17:07:49 - 17:37:29 UTC)
- ... and the [SDU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_Data_Unit) (somewhere between 17:07:49 - 17:37:29 UTC).
  The SDU was repowered, however, at 18:25:27 UTC, when it logged onto the
  Inmarsat satellite network again.

The first 2 items can be easily disabled in the cockpit.
The SDU can be disabled by either turning off the AES circuit breaker in the [E&E bay](https://globusmax.wordpress.com/2015/03/21/the-brains-of-a-boeing-777-simple-and-complex/) or depowering the left main AC bus in the cockpit (which results in the collateral loss of various systems).

India has made it mandatory for aircraft flown by Indian operators to install a device reporting the aircraft's location every 15 minutes, thereby preventing the aircraft from disappearing:

> **India makes its aircraft disappearance proof post MH370 incident**
>
> « India has taken several steps to remove any possibility of the
>   aircraft operated by its airlines disappearing without a trace in the
>   aftermath of the shocking incident in March 2014 involving Malysia
>   Airlines’ MH370. It has made it mandatory for aircraft flown by Indian
>   operators having a seating capacity of 19 passengers or takeoff weight
>   of 45 tonnes or more to install a devise that will send location of
>   the aircraft at 15 minute intervals.
>
> The government had ordered airline companies to compulsorily install
>   an **automated aircraft tracking system (ATS)** in all aircraft
>   falling in the above categories. The system will pass location
>   information to ground stations even if the aircraft is flying over the
>   oceans during long international flights throughout the duration of
>   the flight. » ([source](https://www.financialexpress.com/india-news/india-makes-its-aircraft-disappearance-proof-post-mh370-incident-heres-how/1418651/))

Comment: Of course, this only makes the aircraft disappearance-proof if the ATS doesn't happen to fail.