# Can modern aircraft also "disappear"?

Tags: radio-communications

Regarding the events of MH370, if an modern aircraft (like the Dreamliner, or the A350) turn off deliberately all it's radio-communication under control and fly under the radar scope, is it really possible that with so many nowaday technology, there is still no way to know the whereabouts of an aircraft?

Are new fallback location beacons set?

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2160/19)

Comment: Your question does nor make sense without understanding the difference between primary and secondary RADAR. I recommend that you read about these and perhaps rephrase the question.  It is to all intents and purposes impossible for any commercial aircraft to avoid primary RADAR, if in an area of coverage, but trivially easy to disappear from secondary RADAR.

Comment: [And primary radar coverage is not perfect world wide](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2291/609)

Comment: [Terrain masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrain_mask) is a technique used by military aircrafts to avoid (primary) radar.

Comment: Also note that the 777-200ER IS a modern aircraft... the design was less than 20 years old and the airframe was less than 12 years old... It's not the very latest aircraft, but it's pretty new.